# JSONException in android

Tags: php, android, json, phpmyadmin

**LoginActivity.java**

`baseposte` is my Database, `User` is a table which containt `Num_Compte` and `Code_Compte`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String s = e.getString("post");
     JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);

     map.put("num", jObject.getString("nomcompte"));
     map.put("code", jObject.getString("codecompte"));

     mylist.add(map);
}
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php 
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json);

    $link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
    mysql_select_db('baseposte',$link) or die('Cannot select the DB');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user where ".$obj->{'numcompte'}."=Num_Compte and ".$obj->{'codecompte'}."=Code_Compte";
    $result = mysql_query($query) ;

     /* create one master array of the records */
    $posts = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
      while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
      }
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    print(json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts)));

      /* disconnect from the db */
    @mysql_close($link);
  ?>
```

**LogCat Error**
 `JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: Any chance you could just edit that into your question?

Comment: ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,responseHandler);
JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(responseBody);
JSONArray jArray = json2.getJSONArray("posts");
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Comment: Start off checking what is the return from your php code. This way you will be able to limit the cause of the error. When you check that, please edit your question and add the json contents.

Comment: You mean cheking print(json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts))); but the same result JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

Comment: @ftning I mean I need to see the json the php returns. Post it in your question

Comment: try {Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - start");
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,responseHandler);
JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(responseBody);
JSONArray jArray = json2.getJSONArray("posts");
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();